# Add ContentPlaceholder's programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to add a `ContentPlaceHolder` into a Master Page programmatically?

Im trying to add it to the page on the MasterPages `OnInit` method, but the error

> Cannot find ContentPlaceHolder 'xyz' in the master page

pops up before the Master Pages's `OnInit` is even hit?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: have you tried googling it..? here is a link I found just doing a google search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905145/how-to-add-controls-to-the-masterpages-content-placeholder-programmatically

Comment: @DJKRAZE - the OP is asking if you can create actual content placeholders at run-time, not adding controls at run-time to already existing content placeholders.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Understand the difference between adding `ContentPlaceHolder`s to the page programatically and adding content *to* the ContentPlaceHolders programatically.

Answer (score -3):

You can create two masterpages and select which one load on the PreInit event.

It's explained here: [Changing Master Page at Runtime](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15479/Changing-Master-Page-at-Runtime)

Comment: So if I want to load between 1 and 20 content placeholders you are suggesting I create 20 unique Master Pages?